# Custom unmarshalling golang - object or int

Tags: go, unmarshalling

I'm trying to unmarshall the response from API to one common structure like so:

```
 "status": {
        "title"
        "statusCode"
        "detail"
    }
```

So `status` for instance would be mapped to `statusCode`

```
Below 2 type of responses from API:
{
    "status": {
        "title": "Bad Request",
        "statusCode": 400,
        "detail": "Your request contained technical errors as listed below."
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "propertyPath": "shipments[0].services.visualCheckOfAge",
            "message": "Parameter visualCheckOfAge only allows the values A16 or A18."
        }
    ]
}
```

or

```
{
    "status": 401,
    "title": "Unauthorized",
    "detail": "Unauthorized for given resource."
}
```

I tried custom unmarshalling like so but it fails:

```
type ShipmentOrderResponse struct {
    Status Status  `json:"status"`
    Title  string  `json:"title,omitempty"`
    Detail string  `json:"detail,omitempty"`
    Items  *[]Item `json:"items,omitempty"`
}

type Status struct {
    Title string `json:"title,omitempty"`
    Code  int    `json:"statusCode,omitempty"`
    // Instance A URI reference that identifies the specific occurrence of the problem.
    Instance string `json:"instance,omitempty"`
    // Detail Defines details about the status of the response.
    Detail string `json:"detail,omitempty"`
}
func (s *Status) UnmarshalJSON(d []byte) error {
    for _, b := range d {
        switch b {
        // These are the only valid whitespace in a JSON object.
        case ' ', '\n', '\r', '\t':
        case '{':
            var obj Status
            if err := json.Unmarshal(d, &obj); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            *s = obj
            return nil
        default:
            var code int
            err := json.Unmarshal(d, &code)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            s.Code = code
            return nil
        }
    }
    return errors.New("status must be object or int")
}
```

Any hints I would appreciate , how to tackle this.

Thanks.